# Oracle how do i see who connected to my database

Tags: oracle-11g, listener

I am using oracle 11g and I would like to see who connected to my database some hours ago. In what file can I see those who have connected to my database through a network connection?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming these people are no longer connected, your options may be limited.  Do you enable logging in your listener?  Do you audit logins?  Are you licensed to use the AWR?  Is Statspack installed and running?  How accurate do the results need to be?  Do you need a completely accurate count or can you live with an approximate accounting that relies on various assumptions?  Are you looking for the Oracle user that was logged in or are you trying to get information about the operating system user, client machine, etc?

Comment: Thank Justin. I am looking more for something outside of querying the audit trail. I am exploring more on the listener and oracle network environment. Does a file like the listener log file provide such information, even for a short period?

Comment: If you have enabled logging at the listener, and assuming the listener was used to establish the connection, it will write out a file of every connection attempt.  But that is generally something that you'd need to enable not something that would be done by default.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/trouble.htm#NETAG429

Answer (score 1):

you need auditing in your database, by default Oracle database audit LOGON/LOGOFF action, please take a look into following article [Auditing in Oracle 10g Release 2](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/auditing-10gr2). query from DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL is a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Toad for Oracle, go to the top left corner. You should see a pair of glasses with a AC outlet picture- that is the Session Browser.

Once clicked, it should open a few tabs: Sessions, locks, rbs usage, waits

Session will tell you the machine they are connected to, the SID, the status of the connection, and the type.

Comment: That's who's connected *right now*, not who connected hours ago